# Como fazer upload de multiplos arquivos pelo celular?

Tags: php, html, android

Galera estou tentando subir umas IMG para minha aplicação em php, no pc eu consigo selecionar varios arquivos, mas no celular eu só consigo selecionar uma.
* Uso o android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme o [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple) não é suportado pelo navegador nativo do *Android*, o único que suporta *"parcialmente"* é o *Chrome* para *Android*.

Não há muito o que fazer fora isso, no entanto dependendo da sua necessidade você pode criar um aplicativo para *Android* próprio e usar [*EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE), requer API level 18 (Android 4.3), para selecionar múltiplos arquivos.